# get image files from directory on server for further processing

Tags: php, image, file-upload, upload, readdir

I have folders on the server that contain image files. I'm trying to get those files and then upload them further, but I think I'm using the wrong function.

My code:

```
$dir = "../uploads/".$folderimage."/";
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
  while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
    if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
      echo "$entry\n";
      $handle =  fopen($entry,"wb");
      $mug->images_upload(array( "AlbumID" => "#####", "File" =>   $handle));
    }
  }
  closedir($handle);
}
```

Not sure what I am doing, all I need to do is pass the file to the class function `$mug->images->upload`. It works from a `$_POST` request but I need to move the files already uploaded to the folder.

Comment: Is your images_upload method expecting a filename or the images data?

Comment: You're using `$handle` twice, once for the directory, then inside the loop when you `fopen` the image file.

Comment: post the details of method images_upload, as the method suggest is for upload handling

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky to emulate a file upload POST request for your $mug object. You would be better off if you could refactor the code in $mug as follows:

1. $mug fetches the uploaded file and puts it to its destination place.
2. You create a new function that implements the processing you wish to use here and in $mug.
3. Call this function from here, and from $mug with the appropriate filename.

Answer (score 0):

If `$mug->images_upload` is expecting the file path then pass `$dir.$entry` to it

```
<?php 
$dir = "../uploads/".$folderimage."/";

if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            echo $entry.PHP_EOL;
            $mug->images_upload(array( "AlbumID"=>"#####", "File"=>$dir.$entry));
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}


//Or simpler way but slightly slower
foreach (glob($dir."*.{png,jpg,gif}", GLOB_BRACE) as $file) {
    echo $file.PHP_EOL;
    $mug->images_upload(array( "AlbumID"=>"#####", "File" =>$dir.$file));
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of apparent issues with the code that you have posted.

```
$dir = "../uploads/".$folderimage."/";
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
  while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
    if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
      echo "$entry\n";
      $handle =  fopen($entry,"wb");
      $mug->images_upload(array( "AlbumID" => "#####", "File" =>   $handle));
    }
  }
  closedir($handle);
}
```

- **Clashing variables.**

  You have used the `$handle` vairable to store the directory handle, only to later overwrite it with a file resource inside the loop.  As soon as you overwrite it inside the loop, the next call to `readdir($handle)` does not make any sense are you are calling the function on a file resource.  This could very easily lead to an infinite loop since when `readdir()` is given rubbish, it might return `NULL`.
- **Incorrect path for `fopen()`**

  Given `$folderimage = "images"` and `$entry = "photo.jpg"`, then the `fopen()` line will try to open the image at `photo.jpg` rather than `../uploads/images/photo.jpg`. You likely wanted to use something like `$dir . $entry`, but read on as you shouldn't be using `fopen()` at all.
- **Incorrect usage of the phpSmug library**

  The `File` argument must be a *string* containing "the path to the local file that is being uploaded" ([source](https://github.com/lildude/phpSmug/blob/7514bf975462/phpSmug.php#L600)).  You instead try to pass a *file resource* from `fopen()` to it.
- **`opendir()/readdir()` for directory iteration is ancient**

  There are better ways to traverse directory contents in PHP. As mentioned in [Lawrence's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13435044/113938), `glob()` might be useful.

  I would also advocate using the [filesystem iterator](http://php.net/filesystemiterator) from the [SPL](http://php.net/spl).

  ```
  $dir = "../uploads/$folderimage/";
  foreach (new FilesystemIterator($dir) as $fileinfo) {
      $image_pathname = $fileinfo->getPathname();
      $mug->images_upload("AlbumID=#####", "File=$image_pathname");
  }
  ```