# php get images from folder and read the name of them

Tags: php

Hey here is what i want to do:

I have a folder "images" which contains images named like "MB_FM_Example.png".

I want to loop through the folder and echo the images. Something like that:

```
<?php
$files = scandir('images/');
if ($files !== false) 
{
foreach(is_array($files) as $f) {
if ($f == '..' || $f == '.')
?>
<li><img src="<?php echo 'images/'.$f ?>" alt="<?php echo $f ?>" title="">
<?php
}
} 
?>
```

I need the images to have an url depending on the name of the image. For example image "MB_**FM**_Example1.png" will get the url "Examplepage?v=**FM**"

How can i realize this with php?

Thanks guys

EDIT:

I need just a part of the filename like in my example "FM" and i want the images to get an url like `<a href="examplepage?v=FM"> <img src="IMAGEPATH"> </a>`

Comment: [**DirectoryIterator**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php)

Comment: I would use glob and strpos

Comment: use $_GET['v'] for the FM,
<?php echo 'images/'.$_GET['v'] ?>

Comment: Thanks. Since i am a beginner this is still too much to combine.. How would i implement this in the loop, and trim the FM so i will get the ?v=FM

Comment: @TheodorSolbjørg i think you've misunderstood me. I don't have an url with a variable. I want the variable to come from the imagenames.

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13434909/get-image-files-from-directory-on-server-for-further-processing/13435044#13435044 . **Suggestion use the search feature**

Comment: returning the filenames is not enough. i need to echo the images like that:  <a href="examplepage?v=FM"> <img src="IMAGEPATH"> </a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i was searching for:

```
<?php
      // perform actions for each file found
      foreach (glob("images/*.png") as $filename) {
         $filenamepart = explode("_", $filename);
        echo "<a href='examplepage?v=".$filenamepart[1]."'> <img src='".$filename."'> </a>";
      }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://php.net/glob and the related examples

Something like `glob('yourpathname/')` will return an array of all files in the directory, from there on you just iterate through the array to get each filename.

Comment: Ok but i need just a part of the filename like in my example "FM" and i want the images to get a link like <a href="examplepage?v=FM"> <img sr="IMAGEPATH"> </a>